# How to enable bigvideo.js user controls?

Tags: jquery, html, video

I am using this theme on my website: http://themeforest.unitedthemes.com/themes/brooklyn/yellow/index-video.htm

Problem is, the video plugin only accepts youtube videos and I need one it to use vimeo or just html5 (youtube puts ads everywhere.)

But I can't seem to find one that works the way I want? I need it to display a full width and full height video initially, and have player controls. I will need a 'scroll down' button overlayed on top so that you can view the website underneath (like in the theme).

I was thinking I could use bigvideo.js, but I can't make the player controls work for me and I don't know if I can have content appear 'underneath' the full screen video?

Anyways I think I could compromise seeing as my problem is a bit big for me, I just need to know how to make the video controls work on bigvideo.js?

I found that I could add this

```
<a href="#" id="big-video-control-play">Background Pause/Play</a>
```

But I think there is some jquery behind it to make it work but I don't know what it is? Can anyone help me??

Comment: have a look at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

Comment: Sorry when I said fullscreen, I mean like full width & full height video, like you're using background-size:cover on a video, but still able to have content underneath it like the theme I linked.

Comment: use bigvideo.js with video.js - http://www.videojs.com/